# editText and textView are unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I was making a simple read write file i have done all the code for view binding and everything in xml file gradle build was all fine but `myFile.writeText(editText.text.toString())` shows error editText is unresolved reference `textView.text = myFile.readText()` textView is unresolved reference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FylLT.png) layout and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9FgK.png) the code of MainActivity it will be very helpful if you look at it thanks

I tried to fix it by writing binding.editText same with textView hoping it would work it didnt
I am expecting some fixes in my code or any other way

Answer (score 0):

to get view components you should use binding reference like this: `binding.editText` and `binding.textView` or using [with](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#with) kotlin scope function like this:

```
with(binding) {
    editText...
    textView...
}
```

Comment: can you explain in some more details please

Comment: @Abhaytiwari if you are using view binding you cant access any views without binding reference that's why you get unresolved reference error, but if will access your views through binding reference (like this: binding.editText and binding.textView) the error will gone

Comment: oh you mean to say i should write this instead myFile.writeText(Binding.editText.toString())

binding.textView.text=myFile.readText() ?? i tried this code worked properly but it was not showing results in emulator should i do this in my phone?

Comment: exactly, as for emulator hard to say what's wrong here, maybe you didn't grant the permissions to write files..